# Calculate the sum of the coefficients

Tags: functions

If f(x) = $x^3-(a-2)x^2+bx+c$
calculate a+b+c (Answer:4)
[image]

I try: $f(x)= x^3-(a-2)x^2 +bx+c\\
0 = 2^3-(a-2)2^2+2b+c\\
0 = 8-4a+8+2b+c\rightarrow \boxed{4a-2b-c=16}\\
x=0\rightarrow y=0-0+0=c\rightarrow y = c$

But i stopped here..I don't see another equation

Comment: Data insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Since $2$ is a repeated root, $(x-2)^2$ divides $f(x)$, i.e. $$f(x) = (x^2-4x+4)( x +d)= x^3+(d-4)x^2+(4-4d)x +4d$$

Comparing the constant term, $d=\frac c4$ and comparing the rest gives $$ a-2=4-\frac c4 \\ b=4-c $$ Adding up, $$a+b+c = 10-\frac c4 $$

This means the answer is dependent on $c=f(0)$. If you can provide that, the question is complete.